# In a XSD, define an attribute for a type defined in another XSD

Tags: xsd

Imaging the following xsd's:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    targetNamespace="http://www.example.org/Something" xmlns="http://www.example.org/Something"
    elementFormDefault="qualified">

    <xs:complexType name="SomethingType">
        <xs:attribute name="first" type="xs:string" />
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:element name="Something" type="SomethingType"/>

    ...

</xs:schema>
```

... and ...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    targetNamespace="http://www.example.org/Extension" xmlns="http://www.example.org/Extension"
    xmlns:sth="http://www.example.org/Something" elementFormDefault="qualified">

    <xs:import namespace="http://www.example.org/Something"
        schemaLocation="Something.xsd" />

</xs:schema>
```

How can I define an extra attribute (ie 'second') for the *SomethingType* in the extension schema? I want to create xml like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<sth:Root xmlns:sth="http://www.example.org/Something" xmlns:ext="http://www.example.org/Extension">
    <sth:Something
        sth:first="foo"
        ext:second="bar"/>
</sth:Root>
```

Comment: Have you solved this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Try this way ...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    targetNamespace="http://www.example.org/Something" xmlns="http://www.example.org/Something"
    elementFormDefault="qualified">

    <xs:complexType name="SomethingType">
        <xs:attribute name="first" type="xs:string" />
    </xs:complexType>

</xs:schema>
```

and..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="http://www.example.org/Extension" xmlns="http://www.example.org/Extension"
    xmlns:sth="http://www.example.org/Something" elementFormDefault="qualified">

    <xs:import namespace="http://www.example.org/Something" schemaLocation="Something.xsd" />

    <xs:complexType name="SomethingTypeSecond">
        <xs:complexContent>
            <xs:extension base="sth:SomethingType">
                <xs:attribute name="second" type="xs:string" />
            </xs:extension>
        </xs:complexContent>
    </xs:complexType>

</xs:schema>
```

I hope I've given you all the answers about your question.